# Blocking chrome.tabCapture

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, drm

I am writing a Web Game that relies a lot on WebAudio, and am currently looking for a way to stop extensions from getting the Web Page audio via `chrome.tabCapture`. So far, my search has yielded no results.

I expected Chrome to implement a way to protect Web Media, as a lot of websites display protected media. However, there seems to be no way to block `tabCapture`, and it even works on DRM protected pages such as Spotify and Netflix.